# Why does this update query not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am pretty new with SQL Server and DBMS and I have some problem with the following query that upade a single record of a table named: **MaliciousCodeAlertDocument**

This is my query:

```
UPDATE MaliciousCodeAlertDocument 
SET Discovered = GetDate(), 
    LastUpdated = GetDate(), 
    SourceId = "UP", 
    MalCodeID = 1,
    Title = "UPDATED",
    Origin =  "UP", 
    Type = "UP",
    Feature = "UP",
    Risk = "UP",
    Severity = 1,
    OverallImpact = 1,
    ContagionPotential = 1,
    Wild = "UP",
    AlertStatusID = 1,
    AttributeType = 1,
    DetailLevel = 1  ,
    Language = 1  ,
    Summary = "UP"  ,
    Symptom = "UP"  ,
    TechnicalDescription = "UP"  ,
    MitigatingStrategy = "UP"  ,
    Disinfection = "UP"  ,
    URL = "UP" 
WHERE Id = 11316
```

When I try to execute it I obtain the following error message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UPDATED'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UP'.
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Tnx

Comment: Replace your double quotes with single quotes and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using double-quotes makes SQL Server think that the value within the quotes is a column, but it looks like you're trying to update it to a text value.  If you use single quotes instead, SQL will recognize that you want to insert that value into your field, and should load it correctly.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that @scragar already posted this solution.  Anyone know if I'm supposed to delete my answer because of this?

Comment: Keep your answer. You can't mark a comment as "correct".

Comment: @AHiggins Scragar posted it in a comment which can't be marked as correct and harder to see.  Even if you both posted the same answer independently I would keep both answers and let the community choose which is the better explanation.

Comment: Well I sent an uptick his way on the comment: if he chooses to repost his own comment as an answer, then it should probably take precedence over my own.  For what it's worth.  Going to go see if I can find something on meta.stackexchange about it ... thanks for the inputs.